# OpenAi Gymnasium Observation returning an array of 0's

Tags: python, openai-gym

I am trying to implement a q-learning algorithm on the Atari 2600 version of Donkey Kong, but I cannot get the observation data to work. Using the following code results in `observation` being a 3D array of size 210x160 completely filled with 0's.

```
import gymnasium as gym
import numpy as np

env = gym.make('ALE/DonkeyKong-v5', render_mode='human')

observation, info = env.reset()

for _ in range(1000):
    observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    print(observation)

    if terminated or truncated:
        env.reset()
```

I've tried changing `render_mode` to `'rgb_array'`, as well as a variety of gymnasium pre-processing wrappers and the issue still persists.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you really checked that the `observation` is a zero matrix? I don't think so. You might just check that the very front and the very end of the matrix are 0.

The most part of the Donkey Kong frame is black, which means `[0,0,0]`. This makes you believe the `observation` is full with 0.

Change `print(observation)` to `print(np.sum(observation))` and see what happens.